# Delete values from table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (php) with delete button besides each of the row. I tried to pass the id of the row through submit button to my query. It doesn't have error when I submit but the row is not deleted.

Here's the sourcecode my table:

```
<?php
include ("dbh.php");

$sql_showBooking = "SELECT tid, ticket, bk_email, price FROM ticket_purchase";
$result = $conn->query($sql_showBooking);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>No.</th><th>Ticket</th><th>Email</th><th>Price</th>
<th>Action</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row["tid"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["ticket"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["bk_email"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["price"]."</td>";
        echo '<form novalidate="novalidate" role="form" method="post" action="delete.php?id='.$row['tid'].'">
            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-block" name="btnDelete" value="Delete"/></td>
          </from>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

PHP (delete)

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("dbh.php");

if(isset($_POST["btnDelete"])){

    $tid_delete = $_POST ['tid'];

    $sql_delete = "delete from ticket_purchase where tid='$tid_delete'";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_delete);

    mysqli_close($conn);

    header("Location: Coldplay.php");
}

?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: First you will need to understand how HTTP GET and POST requests work, and how to PHP handles these different request types. Go read up on this.. Then basically your 'Delete' button needs to send a POST request back to the server. Easy way to do this, is to wrap a <FORM> tag around your button, change the button type to 'submit' and make sure you also include and record ID as a hidden field inside same <FORM>.

Comment: Thank you. I just did but seems like its not returning the id from my form to my query

Comment: @SyntaxGoonoo I just edited my post according to your suggestion, can you take a look?

Comment: The id value needs to be rendered into a <input type="hidden" /> field inside the <FORM>, not added as a url parameter. A POST request submits data back to the server via form fields. Only a GET request uses url parameters. It is important that you understand this. You should read up on HTTP request methods and RESTful architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php
include ("dbh.php");

$sql_showBooking = "SELECT tid, ticket, bk_email, price FROM ticket_purchase";
$result = $conn->query($sql_showBooking);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>No.</th><th>Ticket</th><th>Email</th><th>Price</th>
<th>Action</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row["tid"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["ticket"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["bk_email"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row["price"]."</td>";
        echo '<td><a href = "delete.php?tid='.$row['tid'].' ">Delete</a></td>'; //change this line
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>


<?php
session_start();
include ("dbh.php");

if(isset($_REQUEST["tid"])){ //change

    $tid_delete = $_REQUEST['tid']; //changes

    $sql_delete = "delete from ticket_purchase where tid='$tid_delete'";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_delete);

    mysqli_close($conn);

    header("Location: Coldplay.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: It works! Well I don't really understand the method, will try to figure it out. Thank you very much!

Comment: $_REQUEST includes both $_GET and $_POST, which makes the code above regardless of which HTTP method was used.

Comment: Okay noted. Really appreciate that I can learn smtg new here. Thanks again

Comment: Ideally a record should be deleted via a POST request. i.e. GET pulls data from the server, but doesn't change it. POST sends data to the server with the intention of changing the state of that data in the underlying data store e.g. update or delete.

Answer (score 0):

Though the form does send a POST request, the data itself is sent through GET as evidenced by the action attribute : `action="delete.php?id='.$row['tid'].'">`

You can either use $_GET instead of $_POST in delete.php, or you can add a hidden input to the form and set its value to $row['tid'] :

```
<input type = "hidden" value = "<?= $row['tid'] ?>" />
```

Comment: It comes out that the query is work as it leads me to the location inside the (if isset), but the value doesn't change as well. Anyway it works now thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, glad you got it fixed.